# Trim all characters before an integer in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos

I have an alpha numeric string say for example,

`abc123bcd` , `bdfnd567`, `dfd89ds`.

I want to trim all the characters before the first appearance of any integer in the string.

My result should look like,

`abc` , `bdfnd`, `dfd`.

I am thinking of using `substr`. But not sure how to check for a string before first appearance of an integer.

Comment: Sounds more like you want to trim all characters to the right from the first digit on.

Comment: I'm assuming your second example is a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily remove the characters you don't want with [`preg_replace` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and a regular expression:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\d.*$#', '', $str);
```

`\d` matches a digit and `.*$` matches any character until the end of the string.

Learn more about regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/CXy8GkVJ)

Answer (score 3):

A possible non-Regex solution would be:

- [strcspn — Find length of initial segment not matching mask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php)
- [substr — Return part of a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Example:

```
$string = 'foo1bar';
echo substr($string, 0, strcspn($string, '1234567890')); // gives foo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'abc123bcd';
preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $string);
```

or

```
trim($string, '0123456789');
```

Comment: The second one wouldn't do anything because the digits are not at the beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this?

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/^[a-z]+/", "dfd89ds", $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // returns dfd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this:

```
$string = 'abc123bcd';
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*/i', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

will produce:

```
abc
```

Comment: FYI, the `i` modifiers enables case-insensitive matching. I.e. `a` will match either `a` or `A`. When you set this modifier you don't have to provide both, lower-case and upper-case ranges. `/^[a-z]*/i` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the +/- sign, you can simply use:

[abs($number)](https://www.php.net/abs)

and get the absolute value.

e.g

```
$abs = abs($signed_integer);
```